# how to load a value in textbox at program startup

Tags: c#, textbox, startup

i managed to do somehow what i want by doing this

```
    private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "a1";
    }
```

But i want this to happen without clicking on the textbox 
The way i did upper required me to click before a1 will be written there.

Comment: Is this winforms, WPF, ASP, silverlight, etc.?

Comment: can you be more specific, are you trying to load values from a .config file..? also show better formatted code..

Comment: Definitely need more information

Comment: Matei i suggest code sample in order to read appsetting

Comment: check for the events for the form and write your code in the appropriate one

Answer (score 4):

You need to do it in the [`Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx) event of your form

```
private void YourFormName_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string someValue="Get the value from wherever you want";
     textBox1.Text = someValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shyju, that is what i want

Comment: This makes the assumption that it's winforms.  If that's no the case, the answer will be different.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you need read global variable of config , in appsetting

```
NameValueCollection appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
textBox1.Text = appSettings["yourkey"];
```